# Why does the shape of my function change when plotted alongside another function?

Tags: plotting

I wanted to investigate the periodicity of functions so I tried to `Plot` them on Mathematica using the `Plot` function.

The particular function was $\cos(\cos(x))+\cos(\sin(x))$.

What I did was first plot them individually, then together. Individual results were as follows:

```
Plot[Cos[Cos[x]], {x, -4, 4}, Ticks -> {Table[x*Pi, {x, -2, 2, 1/2}],
{1.530, 1.535, 1.540}}, AspectRatio -> .1]
```

[image: diagram 1]

```
Plot[Cos[Sin[x]], {x, -4, 4}, Ticks -> {Table[x*Pi, {x, -2, 2, 1/2}], 
{1.530, 1.535, 1.540}}, AspectRatio -> .1]
```

[image: diagram 2]

```
Plot[Cos[Cos[x]] + Cos[Sin[x]], {x, -4, 4}, Ticks -> {Table[x*Pi, {x, -2, 2, 1/2}],
{1.530, 1.535, 1.540}}, AspectRatio -> .1]
```

[image: diagram 3]

Now all together:

```
Plot[{Cos[Cos[x]], Cos[Sin[x]], Cos[Cos[x]] + Cos[Sin[x]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, Ticks ->
{Table[x*Pi, {x, -1, 1, 1/2}]}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: diagram 4]

See the yellow plot? That's supposed to be my original function but the individual function plot seems to be very different. Why is that so? Is it some system error or is it my fault?

Comment: Please use the site's built-in image uploader.  If you use external image hosting, the images will likely disappear with time (most services don't keep them indefinitely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the plots are correct, but what may be catching you out is the windowing of the Y-axis and your tick specification. Adding `PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 2}}` should help you see what is happening.

```
Plot[Cos[Cos[x]], {x, -4, 4}, Ticks -> {Table[x*Pi, {x, -2, 2, 1/2}]},
  AspectRatio -> .1, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Cos[Sin[x]], {x, -4, 4}, Ticks -> {Table[x*Pi, {x, -2, 2, 1/2}]},
  AspectRatio -> .1, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So for the combined plot you would get:

```
Plot[{Cos[Cos[x]], Cos[Sin[x]], Cos[Cos[x]] + Cos[Sin[x]]}, {x, -Pi, 
  Pi}, Ticks -> {Table[x*Pi, {x, -1, 1, 1/2}]}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks for the answer but how come the ticks were affecting the range of the function ?

Comment: BTW how did you get such perfect screen shots?

Comment: @The-Ever-Kid In your first two plots the specifications for the Y ticks are such that they are not visible since they are at {1.530, 1.535, 1.540}, which are not in the displayed range of the plot.

Comment: and about the screenshots?

Comment: @The-Ever-Kid I use a palette control built by szabolcs, I was looking for the link - but haven't tracked it down yet. Here it is http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes.

Comment: Is there a reason that you didn't upload the images to StackExchange instead of a third-party service?

Comment: @celtschk not in my case, it was the first method I came across and seems very convenient.

Comment: The problem is that if those images ever disappear from the third-party service (maybe because the third-party service shuts down, maybe because of some built-in expire, maybe because at some time in the future you yourself don't remember what those images were for and delete them), this question breaks. With uploading to StackExchange, the probability of losing those images is considerably lower. (And BTW, third-party image links make the life harder for people like me who don't by default let the browser automatically access arbitrary third-party content for security reasons).

Comment: @celtschk Interesting, I just assumed that as it was provided by one of the most active members and is the top answer to the question I linked to addressing uploading images to SE that it would be an acceptable way. Should the answer be edited to reflect what you have said ?

Comment: @celtschk are you referring to Szabolcs's image uploader? that uploads the images to the same server as  the one used by stackexchange/stackoverflow itself.

Comment: @Heike: I now notice that I happened to use the wrong comment button; I meant to add the comment to the question, not to the answer.

Comment: @image_doctor: Sorry about the confusion; I was a bit careless in checking both where I added the original comment, and when you replied, I didn't check who write the comment but just assumed that it was the one writing the question because I thought that's where I had added the comment. In short: You did nothing wrong, The-Ever-Kid did.

Comment: @celtschk so now You're blaming me?

Comment: @The-Ever-Kid: You put your images on a third-party server (puu.sh), didn't you?

Comment: @celtschk OK I understand now.

Comment: so thats wrong?..